# Git -- Two different branches contain the same changes

Tags: git, branch

I created a branch and made some changes -- deleted/added files, changed contents, etc. I then realized I needed to do something else unrelated and, without commiting (because I wasn't finished with the first branch) went back to master and created a new branch. I then added what I needed in my second branch but when I went to commit it contained all the status info from my other branch. I don't want this...

EDIT: I'm currently trying to undo the git add --all from my second branch. I'm nervous to do a git reset in case it resets for both branches. How do I revert the second branch safely, and how do I avoid having ucommitted changes visible in all branches in the future?

Comment: Are you looking for a solution to a problem, or retrospect on what you should have done?

Comment: apparently you did a soft reset to master. The content of the file were left untouched, but the current head was pointed to master. Therefore, all modifications were kept. Yes, a stash would have worked better. From were you stand, you can probably revert all the commits on the other branch, or create a patch from the head of the other branch down to the separation point, then apply that, then possibly squash commits before pushing.

Comment: @Chris I edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: Re edit, it sounds like your mental model may be missing a piece: when you `git add` items git merely stuffs them into the "index" (aka "staging area").  That means it does not affect any branch *yet*.  A general trick for saving both index and work-tree stuff is to use `git stash`: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing

Comment: @jtsmith1287 You can take a look at [Legit](http://www.git-legit.org/), it are some tools for an alternative workflow with git, maybe it fits your needs and you can avoid such confusion in the future.